# How to fix errors in a method using OOP programming

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have the below code, where the `get()` method looks to grab all of the values in my dataframe (which is an excel sheet full of data) where the contents of that excel cell begin with the text `"AML"`:

```
class Settings3:
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.path = path
        self.data = self.load()
          
    def load(self):
        if self.path.endswith('.xlsx'):
            print ("This is a valid file path")
        else:
            raise Exception("This is not a valid file path")
        #LOAD WORKBOOK
        self.workbook = load_workbook(filename=self.path)
        # CREATE THE DICTIONARY TO HOLD DATAFRAMES\n",
        self.data_dict = {}
        # GO THROUGH SHEETS, STORING SHEETNAME AND DATAFRAME\n",
        for sheet in self.workbook.sheetnames:
            self.data_dict[sheet] = pd.read_excel(self.path, sheet_name=sheet)
        return self.data_dict

    def get(self,value):
        if value == None:
            return self.data
        elif value in self.workbook.sheetnames:
            df = pd.read_excel(self.path, value)
            return df
        elif value == "AML":
            for sheet_name in self.workbook.sheetnames:
                df = pd.read_excel(self.path,sheet_name)
                if "RULE_ID" in df.columns:
                    print(df.loc[df["RULE_ID"] == value])
```

Currently, when I try the get method `s3.get("AML")` (using `s3` as an instance of that `settings3` object, I receive the below values as output

```
Empty DataFrame Columns: [RULE_ID, PARAM_ID, ROLE_ID, PARAM_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_VALUE, SQL] Index: []
Empty DataFrame Columns: [REGION_CD, RULE_ID, PARAM_ID, ROLE_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_VALUE, TENANT_CD, SQL] Index: []
Empty DataFrame Columns: [REGION_CD, RULE_ID, PARAM_ID, ROLE_ID, PARAM_NAME, THRESHOLD_NAME, THRESHOLD_VALUE, TENANT_ID, SQL] Index: []
Empty DataFrame Columns: [REGION_CD, RULE_ID, PARAM_ID, PARAM_NAME, FROM_VALUE, SCORE, TENANT_ID, SQL] Index: []
Empty DataFrame Columns: [REGION_CD, RULE_ID, PARAM_ID, ROLE_ID, PARAM_NAME, THRESHOLD_NAME, POPULATION_GROUP_ID, THRESHOLD_VALUE, TENANT_ID, SQL] Index: []
Empty DataFrame Columns: [REGION_CD, RULE_ID, PARAM_ID, PARAM_NAME, POPULATION_GROUP_ID, FROM_VALUE, SCORE, TENANT_ID, SQL] Index: []
Empty DataFrame Columns: [RULE_ID, PARAM_ID, PARAM_NAME, ROLE_ID, ENTITY_KEY, THRESHOLD_NAME, THRESHOLD_VALUE, TENANT_ID, SQL] Index: []
Empty DataFrame Columns: [RULE_ID, PARAM_ID, PARAM_NAME, ENTITY_KEY, FROM_VALUE, SCORE, TENANT_ID, SQL] Index: []
```

The values that should be returned should look something like this (from the actual excel sheet):

```
0   AML-ADR-ADR-ALL-A-M06-CUS
1   AML-ADR-ADR-ALL-A-M06-CUS
2   AML-ADR-ADR-ALL-A-M06-CUS
3   AML-ADR-ADR-ALL-A-M06-CUS
```

Can anyone help with why this may be? It must be a small error in my `get()` code. Thank you :)

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question. Read the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for instructions on how to format code properly.

Comment: Also please include the full stacktrace, you're not showing where the error message comes from

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have edited the question which is hopefully in better shape now.

Comment: @joao apologies, there was no actual Python error message, and just the output (which is obviously wrong)

Comment: I have fixed the formatting properly, and added a tag for openpyxl. Please edit the title of your question into something that informs about the *specific* question you are asking, and also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and see how much you can figure out yourself. For example, does `self.workbook.sheetnames` look like what you expect? Is the `if "RULE_ID" in df.columns` check passed? Does the result `df["RULE_ID"]` look like what you expect? How about `df["RULE_ID"] == value`?

Comment: You should also update your code to be a complete, self-contained example. We should (assuming the proper libraries are installed) be able to run your code as is (in particular, include the appropriate `import` statements), with a small example input, and reproduce the problem.

Comment: There are a few basic problems, I think.  In `get(),` why are you using `pd.read_excel`?  You already created `data_dict,` which is full of dataframes, one for each worksheet.  Also, in your `__init__(),` you call `self.data = self.load()`, which loads a dict into data.  You seem to be unintentionally switcheing between dict and pd.DataFrame structures at various places.  Once those issues are resolved, you can update your get() method to reference df = data_dict[sheet] instead of pd.read_excel.  I'm unsure what you are trying to do in that last if statement.  Please clarify.

Comment: Also, it looks like it may be incomplete code.  Please include the entirety of the function and sample data. The community should be able to run whatever you data and code you provide in order to reproduce the issue on our end. Please comment the code with what you want each section to do, so we can determine if it is meeting that intent.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to grab all of the values that *begin* with the text "AML", but
your code tests for equality instead:

```
df["RULE_ID"] == value
```

This would only match a cell that contains the exact "AML" string, not
"AML_hello" or anything like that. Now in python you have the `startswith`
string method which would come in handy here, but unfortunately this is not a
vectorized operation on Series.

So the trick is to write a function that performs the operation you want:

```
f = lambda x: str(x).startswith('AML')
```

and apply it to the series (replacing the last line of your code):

```
print(df.loc[df["RULE_ID"].apply(f)])
```

The conversion to string with `str()` is just to avoid crashing on a integer, for
example.